# How best can I summarise the following table data frame in R?

Tags: r

How best can I summarise the following table data frame in R?

```
Driver_ID <- c('AB1','AB1')

Date_today<- as.Date(c('2018-10-24','2018-10-24'))

Motor_Vehicle_Brand <- c('Toyota','VW')

Type_of_vehicle <- c('Corrola','Golf 5')

Country <- c('USA','USA')

Speed <- as.numeric(c('300','400'))

Number_of_brands_drived <- as.numeric(c('1','1'))

car.data <- data.frame(Driver_ID, Date_today,       Motor_Vehicle_Brand,Type_of_vehicle,Country,Speed,Number_of_brands_driven)
```

To Show

```
Driver_ID <- 'AB1'
Date_today<- as.Date('2018-10-24')
Motor_Vehicle_Brand <- c('Toyota VW')

Type_of_vehicle <- 'Corrola Golf 5'

Country <- 'USA'

Speed <- as.numeric('700')

Number_of_brands_drived <- as.numeric('2')

car.data <- data.frame(Driver_ID, Date_today,       Motor_Vehicle_Brand,Type_of_vehicle,Country,Speed,Number_of_brands_driven)
```

I have tried the following code, however it fails to group the way I want it to,

```
df %>% 
  group_by(DRIVER_ID, Country) %>% 
  mutate(Highest_speed = sum(Highest speed driven), 
         Number_of_brands_driven = sum(Number_of_brands_drived))
```

this however gives me a ungrouped data which is similar to the unsummarised data.

Please assist.

Comment: Instead of `mutate`, you need to use `summarise`.

Comment: I have edited the code to show a reproducible example. Thanks for the advice Phiver.

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in the comment, you need to use `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
car.data %>% 
  group_by(Driver_ID, Country) %>% 
  summarise(Highest_speed = sum(Speed),
            Number_of_brands_driven = sum(Number_of_brands_drived))

# A tibble: 1 x 4
# Groups:   Driver_ID [?]
  Driver_ID Country Highest_speed Number_of_brands_driven
  <fct>     <fct>           <dbl>                   <dbl>
1 AB1       USA               700                       2
```

edit: added Motor_Vehicle_Brand to summary.

To add a brand to a summary without creating double records is to paste the records together.

```
car.data %>%
  group_by(Driver_ID, Country) %>%
  summarise(Highest_speed = sum(Speed),
            Number_of_brands_driven = sum(Number_of_brands_driven),
            brands = paste(Motor_Vehicle_Brand, collapse = ", "))
# A tibble: 1 x 5
# Groups:   Driver_ID [?]
  Driver_ID Country Highest_speed Number_of_brands_driven brands    
  <fct>     <fct>           <dbl>                   <dbl> <chr>     
1 AB1       USA               700                       2 Toyota, VW
```

Comment: Hi, thanks this works beautifully. Is there perhaps a different way that i could still keep the Motor_Vehicle_Brand in some way on the summarised data?